# sphinxcontrib.programoutput works locally, doesn't work on ReadTheDocs

Tags: python, python-sphinx, read-the-docs, autodoc

I am trying to use sphinxcontrib.programoutput to automatically document the `--help` command of my software.

My rst looks like this:

```
.. command-output:: squiggle --help
```

And works exactly as expected locally. However, when I go to put it on ReadTheDocs, I get this error:

```
$ squiggle --help
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/squiggle/envs/latest/bin/squiggle", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('squiggle==0.1', 'console_scripts', 'squiggle')()
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/squiggle/envs/latest/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 565, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/squiggle/envs/latest/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2631, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/squiggle/envs/latest/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2291, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/squiggle/envs/latest/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2297, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
ImportError: No module named 'squiggle'
```

What doesn't make sense to me is that my path seems to be right because autodoc is working.

What could be this source of this problem?

For more information, the logs can be viewed [here](https://readthedocs.org/projects/squiggle/builds/7454044/).

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! I changed

```
py_modules=['squiggle']
```

to

```
packages=['squiggle']
```

in my setup.py file.